# a query result from a selected entity returns null

Tags: eclipse, jpa, eclipselink

i have to retrieve the last visit of a selected patient from datatable the problem is that the query always returns bull , here is the responsible code :

```
public class PatientDao implements Serializable {
......
    public List<String> findWithQuery(String query ,int id) {

 Query q=   this.getEntityManager().createQuery(query).setParameter("id",id);

    return q.getResultList(); 
}
}
......
}


@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PatientCtrl implements Serializable{
......
private static Patient selectedpatient = new Patient();
private static PatientDao pDao = new PatientDao();
private  static String lv   ;
......
public  void lastVisit()
{ 

this.setLv( pDao.findWithQuery("select max(v.date) from Visite v where v.patient.id = :id      ",selectedpatient.getId()).toString().replaceAll("^\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]$", ""));



 }



<h3>Dernière visite</h3>
       <p:outputLabel  value="#{patientCtrl.lv}"   />
```

it s always null

Comment: after the selection of a patient from the datatable a dialog appears
containing  <p:outputLabel  value="#{patientCtrl.lv}"   />

Answer (score 1):

This is a coding mistake as you are selecting Visite with a patient.id=1 and patient=p.  Unless = p.id =1, you will get no results, and so null.  I believe you meant to use setParameter("id",p) instead, but using v.patient.id=:id and v.patient = :p seems redundant and one should be removed anyway.

Comment: Even when i changed it , the result still the same

Comment: WHat data do you have, and what SQL is generated?  What values are returned from just "select v.date from Visite v where v.patient.id = :id"?

Comment: i want to have the last selected patient visit from a datatable to an outputlabel 
    pDao.findWithQuery("select max(v.date) from Visite v where v.patient.id = :id      ",selectedpatient.getId()).toString(); and i put the result in static string variable (lv)

Comment: Why are you calling toString on a List instead of retrieving the String contained within the List?  And you still haven't mentioned what the query SQL issued is or the data you have in the database.

Comment: when i replace :id with a real number like 1, it retruns a result but when i use selectedpatient.getId() the query returns [null], findWithQuery returns a list in this case returns just one string (date) so i put tostring
PS there is not exception just null in outputlabel

Comment: What is the SQL?  From the sounds of it, the id being used doesn't have visite entities associated to it.

Comment: what do you mean "what is the SQL" ? it s onetomany relationship between patient and visit

Comment: Your JPQL query gets converted to SQL which is sent to the database.  If you turn on logging to Finest, you will see the SQL statement that is issued to the database in the logs.

Comment: You mean this
SELECT t1.ID_ANALYSE_ANNUELLE, t1.TEST_PODOLOGIQUE, t1.TRIGLYCERIDE, t1.TEST_CARDIOVASCULAIRE, t1.MICROALBUMINURIE, t1.CREATININE, t1.LDL, t1.DATE_ANALYSE_ANNUELLE, t1.HDL, t1.TEST_NEUROLOGIQUE, t1.CHL_TOTAL, t1.TEST_OPHTALMOLOGIQUE, t1.PATIENT_ID FROM PATIENT_ANALYSEANNUELLE t0, ANALYSEANNUELLE t1 WHERE ((t0.Patient_ID = ?) AND (t1.ID_ANALYSE_ANNUELLE = t0.analyseAnnuelle_ID_ANALYSE_ANNUELLE))